# Delete NgRx node by LazyLoading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-lazyloading

I'm working in and angular 9 app implementing NgRx with lazy load

when the app loads, my state looks like this

[image]

and when I navigate to the route '/account-config' the state change becouse I have lazy loaded the module and implemented a StoreModule.forFeature int he imports. Then, my state looks like this

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to delete the 'accountconfig' node when I navigate to other route, and put again when I go back to  '/account-config'.

these are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
      { path: 'account-config',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/account-config/account-config.module').then(m => m.AccountConfigModule) },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'session',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/session/session.module').then(m => m.SessionModule) }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'session/not-found'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a way, the `Store` class has a method [`removeReducer`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L126-L128):

```js
removeReducer<Key extends Extract<keyof T, string>>(key: Key) {
  this.reducerManager.removeReducer(key);
}
```

Each slice of the store is associated with a reducer, so you can get rid of some slices by removing their key.

The `Store` class also has: `addReducer`:

```js
  addReducer<State, Actions extends Action = Action>(
    key: string,
    reducer: ActionReducer<State, Actions>
  ) {
    this.reducerManager.addReducer(key, reducer);
  }
```

So I think you can use `store.addReducer(key, reducer)` on `ngOnInit` and `store.removeReducer(key)` on `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work, the 'accountconfig' node is still there

Comment: Not sure why it didn’t work. Are you sure that the node is declared as a reducer? Also, try to use a selector for this slice and when you’re going to another route, it should return undefined

Comment: I think is for the Lazyload in that module... I'm using `StoreModule.forFeature('accountconfig', accountConfigReducer),` in the imports of my account-config.module

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo?